# How to read mails with Graph Azure from microsoft personal account

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service

So I got a hotmail mailbox, which I read from 'https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/', which is part of my personal microsoft account. Basically I just want to read my mails from php, and assign a category to some emails. As it is not possible with imap, I started to search any solution with Azure portal.

I logged in in https://portal.azure.com/ with my Microsoft accound mail adress and passowrd, created an app, gave it some permissions (User.ReadAll, Mail.ReadWrite), get client id, tenant id, and secret, and used this script to open my mailbox : https://github.com/CoasterKaty/PHPGraphMailer/blob/main/graph_mailer.php

I get a token with success, but I have this error code in my webpage : "NoPermissionsInAccessToken The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood". This seems to be, because my app doesn't have grant permission. Searching on Google, seems I have to do that : log in as global administrator and go to Azure > Enterprise applications, and grant permission. As I am the only person using this mail adress, I thought I would be admin, obviously, but it seems not. In any case, the "Enterprise applications" page is running a loading icon endlessly and in the mean time Azure portal display a notification which says "Détails : AADSTS50020: User account '{EmailHidden}' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services' and cannot access the application 'blablablabla' (Azure Portal) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account."

On docs microsoft, they say this error would be linked to "This error message can occur if you have a subscription that is recently expired, inactive, or orphaned. To resolve this, you will either need to claim a new Azure subscription or transfer the subscription to a new account" or "That message can happen if you have a personal "Microsoft" account using the same email address as your O365 "Work or School" account. To resolve this, go to microsoft.com/accounts using an incognito browser so that no credentials carry over, and choose the Microsoft account when logging in".

This is really confusing, is Azure only working when you have 365 ? No need to use it with only Microsoft personal account ?

Many thanks for your support !

Answer (score 0):

> Détails : AADSTS50020: User account '{EmailHidden}' from identity
> provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services' and
> cannot access the application 'blablablabla' (Azure Portal) in that
> tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the
> tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active
> Directory user account."

We have tried to add the User who has personal outlook account and trying to access it through Graph api its throwing the below error:
[image]

[image]

---

If we trying to access one user who is associate and **user type = Member** with our tenant we can able to see the mails from graph API

[image]
[image]

---

> This error message can occur if you have a subscription that is
> recently expired, inactive, or orphaned. To resolve this, you will
> either need to claim a new Azure subscription or transfer the
> subscription to a new account" or "That message can happen if you have
> a personal "Microsoft" account using the same email address as your
> O365 "Work or School" account. To resolve this, go to
> microsoft.com/accounts using an incognito browser so that no
> credentials carry over, and choose the Microsoft account when logging
> in".

This error might occurs If you are using azure free trial , and if your subscription expired you need to get a new azure free trial or convert the free trail to PAy-As-You-Go .Another thing is that even if you are creating azure subscription using your personal mail account ,the users gets stored in the format as shown in below image :

[image]